# C++ gamedev: truncating float to int

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding

I'm making a game in C++ where is a tank that can moves on a stage. The tank has an angle (float, in degrees, and i'm supposing the tank is at 0º when his cannon points to the right), a speed (float), and there is a time constant called "deltaT" (float).

When the player moves the tank forward, I use trigonometry and the physic equation of position in function of time (I mean X(t), I don't know how it says in English) in order to calculate the new tank's coordinates in the stage.

This is my problem: due to the passage from float to int, the values closest to zero are not taken into account. So, at certain angles, the tank appears rotated, but moves in a different direction.

This is what my code does:

1 - first, I separate the speed in its components X and Y, by using the angle in which the tank is moving:

```
    float speedX = this->speed * cos(this->angle);
    float speedY = this->speed * sin(this->angle);
```

2 - then use the equation I mentioned above to get the new coordinates:

```
    this->x = (int) ceil(this->x + (speedX * deltaT));
    this->y = (int) ceil(this->y - (speedY * deltaT));
```

The problem begins at the first step: at certain angles, the value of the cos or the sin is very close to zero.
So, when I multiply it for speed to obtain, say, speedX, I still got a very low number, and then when I multiply it for deltaT it is still too low, and finally when apply the ceil, that amount is totally lost.

For example, at 94º, with deltaT = 1.5, and speed = 2, and assuming initial value of X is 400, we have:

```
speedX = -0.1395...
this->x = 400 //it must be 399.86..., but stays in 400 due to the ceiling
```

So, in my game the tank appears rotated, but moves straight forward. Also, sometimes it moves well backwards but wrong forward, and viceversa.

How can I do to make the direction of the tank more accurate? To raise the speed or the value of deltaT are not options since it's about a tank, not a formula 1.

Comment: +1: good work explaining your question and providing minimal relevant code.

Comment: Storing angles as degrees is rarely useful. C++ natively works in radians. You'll end up converting back and forth. The one exception where you wouldn't use radians is when you have an array of sprites, one for each rotation of the tank. In that case, it can be useful to use the array index instead. But nobody would make 360 sprites; 128 (4x32) would be far more common.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I reallized about the radians too late. But actually, the code that I've posted its a little bit simplified: I don't use the sin and cos functions from math library, but I have tabulated the values of the cos and sin of certain angles, in order to avoid calculate them in runtime.

Also, for the rotated images, I don't have 128 sprites, but I have just one, and use the function "rotozoomSurface" (in SDL_gfx lib, an add on for SDL), that works with degrees.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I do to make the direction of the tank more accurate? To raise the speed or the value of deltaT are not options since it's about a tank, not a formula 1 :P

You should store your position values as `float`s, even though they are ultimately used as `int`s for on-screen positioning. That way, you won't lose the non-integer portion of your position. Just cast to `int` right at the end when you do your drawing.

Answer (score 5):

Keep the location of the tank in `float`s all the time. Alternatively, only let the tank rotate in increments of 45 degrees. Decide on whether your game will use approximate positions and headings or exact ones and stick to that decision all the way through.

Comment: _Alternatively, only let the tank rotate in increments of 45 degrees._

Yes, I've tried that before, but the tank rotated too fast and in a not very fluid way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not accuracy! Floating-point math has 24-bit accuracy, that's plus/minus 1/16,777,216. No problem there.

It's your [rounding mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding). 
`ceil` rounds up.

Try:

```
int x = this->x + (speedX * deltaT) +.5f;
```

`ceil` creates a rounding error (E) of 0<E<1, casting as above gives -.5<E<+.5, which has half the absolute error.

Also, avoid using double math.   `ceil` is the double version, you mean `ceilf`. Technically, your code casts float->double->int. You gain nothing from this, but it takes time.

And finally... The real problem:

Your accuracy problem really is because you are accumulating it! 
So 0<E<1 ... PER FRAME!
at 60Hz => 0<E<60*seconds. Thus after a minute 0<E<3600
If X/Y are pixel coordinates, that's a whole screen! No wonder you are struggling.

No matter how you round, this is always going to be a problem.
Instead, you to store the floating point result before rounding. Thus the absolute error is always 0<E<1 ... or -.5f < E < .5f for mid-point rounding. Try adding a new floating point position - XPos/YPos

```
this->XPos += speedX * deltaT;
this->YPos += speedY * deltaT;
this->x = static_cast<int>(this->XPos+.5f);
this->y = static_cast<int>(this->YPos+.5f);
```

You should now move around smoothly.

PS: The word in English is "parametric", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation